# SVN: Ignore a _versioned_ directory

Tags: svn, svnignore

I am working on a project with a very large svn repository.
One of the directories under source control contains a plethora of very large binary files totaling over 1 GB in size.  I have no interest in these files, they have no impact on the work I am doing.  I would like to perform an svn:update without getting any of the changes for this folder.

Is there a way to exclude a versioned folder/file from getting updates?  I found a handful of questions here and on other sites and they all recommend removing the thing you want to ignore from source control.  Unfortunately I am just a mere peon and have no say in these matters, the files cannot be removed.

Is there a way to do this? Ignore all updates to a versioned directory without making changes to the repository itself.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use the --depth argument to work around it, but there's no way to pretend it isn't there. We ended up restructuring a load of stuff into a /media repository for this exact reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Svn [sparse checkouts](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html) may be what you want for this.